# Compile error: Can't find project or library (OSX)

Tags: macos, vba, excel, excel-2016

I've run into a bit of a problem with making my macros compatible with OSX where it works on windows.

I have the following issue:

> Compile error: Can't find project or library error when running the macro on Office 2016 on a MAC

The code/ function is used to change specific ranges to Upper Case / Proper case. The debugger highlights `"UCase(Cell)"` and `"Cell"`

```
Sub ChkSheet()
'=========================================================================
' Format the cell boarders when the info needs to be corrected or updated
'=========================================================================
Dim historyWks As Worksheet
Set historyWks = Worksheets("Namelist")
Dim lRow As Long
Dim emailRng As Range
Dim Cell As Range

With historyWks

' Flags cells where the Email fieldcontains invalid characters
lRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set emailRng = Range("Q2:Q" & lRow)

    For Each Cell In emailRng
        If Cell.Value = "," _
            Or Cell.Value = " " _
            Or Cell.Value = "wd" _
            Or Cell.Value = "" _
            Or Cell.Find("@") Is Nothing Then
            Cell.Interior.Color = vbRed

            Else:
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

        End If
    Next

     'Change the text case
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

        For Each Cell In Range("NListUpper")
        Select Case True
        Case Application.IsText(Cell) = True
            Cell = UCase(Cell)
        End Select
    Next Cell
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

     'Change the case to proper
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    For Each Cell In Range("NListProp")
        Select Case True
        Case Application.IsText(Cell) = True
            Cell = StrConv(Cell, vbProperCase)
        End Select
    Next Cell
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

 End With

End Sub
```

I've noticed that some libraries are missing on Excel 2016 on OSX and i'm aware that MS has dropped many libraries out of Excel for OSX.

Any advice on this would be just great.

Comment: What references do you have checked? Almost certainly one of them is unavailable on the Mac and that is causing your problem.

Comment: @Rory i've removed the missing ref's and i'm no longer getting the error but excel hangs up completely

Comment: Simply removing them will not necessarily help - they may be needed!

Comment: I aggree, the function works and i'd have to retest all the userforms and macros to be sure that they aren't affected. The i'm almost thinking the ranges are causing a severe performance issue on the OSX Excel application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try avoiding using default properties of the `Range` object - they might differ between Windows and OSX:

So, instead of:

```
Select Case True
    Case Application.IsText(Cell) = True
        Cell = UCase(Cell)
End Select
```

Can you just try:

```
If Application.IsText(Cell.Value) Then
    Cell.Value = UCase(Cell.Value)
End If
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Let me try your suggestion and learn something new :-).
From my understanding, I'm using `Application.IsText` to check the cell for a text value and it applies to Excel 2016, Excel 2013, Excel 2011 for Mac, Excel 2010, Excel 2007, Excel 2003, Excel XP, Excel 2000.

Comment: Wasn't on my VBE intellisense - the idiosyncracy I was referring to was the  `Select Case True... End Select` in any case. My core answer is about specifically using the `Value` property of the `Range` object. I didn't really think the `.IsText` method was an issue per your question. Anyway I edited to remove this 'subjectivity'. HTH

Comment: I see what you mean there thanks for that. I've removed the missing libraries and found that the process worked up to some extent but left Excel hanging. I'm about retry your edit. It's great learning how i can do this in different ways. Thanks for that!

Comment: Nice this helped with the performance hit on the the MAC. I'm guessing that if i play with the ranges i could get the processing time down some more. I had to take auto calculate off though. Maybe i need to find a way to switch calculation on/off when running the application. Thanks for the help